# Already set the resources folder. But getclass().get resource().getPath() still failed in Intellj IDEA Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I ready set the resources folder in it. But the code still not working. But use full file path name works everytime.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Main main = new Main();
        //main.readFile("C:\\Users\\JIAN HE\\IdeaProjects\\DragDrop\\src\\resources\\text.txt");
        main.readFile("text.txt");
        //MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();
        //System.out.println(Main.class.getResource("/resources/elephant.png"));
    }
    public void readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(getClass().getResource(fileName).getPath());

        //File file = new File("C:\\Users\\JIAN HE\\IdeaProjects\\DragDrop\\src\\resources\\text.txt");
        //File file = new File("C:\\Users\\JIAN HE\\IdeaProjects\\DragDrop\\src\\resources\\text.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to add a "/" or the variations from here: [How do I load a file from resource folder?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15749192)

Comment: Do not call getPath() on a URL, ever.  It *does not* return a valid file name.  The proper way to read a resource is with `Main.class.getResourceAsStream()`.  Embedded resources are not guaranteed to be files and should not be treated as files.

Comment: @VGR should I using `File file = new File(String.valueOf(Main.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)));` ?

Comment: No.  Do not use File at all.  Use `InputStream source = Main.class.getResourceAsStream();` followed by `new Scanner(source)`.  An embedded resource is not a file.

Comment: @VGR It works. Thanks!!1

Comment: @VGR one more question. I have one class: DragDropPanel. I tried to add an image as imageicon.  `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/elephant.png");` not working. 
``   `InputStream source1 = DragDropPanel.class.getResourceAsStream("elephant.png"); ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(source1); also not working.

Comment: `new ImageIcon(DragDropPanel.class.getResource("images/elephant.png"))` should work, because [ImageIcon has a constructor that takes a URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URL)).

Comment: @VGR Sorry to bother you. Can you help me solve this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078772/using-springutilities-and-springlayout-cannot-add-another-componentjpanel-to-j) question?